# HTML: Reducing vertical space between two objects (Blogger)

Tags: html, blogger, blogs, space

I'm creating my blog in Blogger, and I added an slider to feature all my last posts, but this slider is far from the title tabs.

[image]

I created the slider as a [Bootstrap widget](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/carousel/), because I'm a rookie in HTML, so I would appreciate if you know how to solve this w/o editing my template and just editing the widget code, but anyway, any answer is welcome.

This is the code:

```
<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-jNCFG9jAclE/X41wSrsqqNI/AAAAAAAAMek/pGuRB9PaWMAH7j13gDBuM-CYHzemQ5lQgCLcBGAsYHQ/w640-h215/andre-sanano-gQ06DrUzNIk-unsplash.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>First slide label</h5>
        <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-jNCFG9jAclE/X41wSrsqqNI/AAAAAAAAMek/pGuRB9PaWMAH7j13gDBuM-CYHzemQ5lQgCLcBGAsYHQ/w640-h215/andre-sanano-gQ06DrUzNIk-unsplash.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Second slide label</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-jNCFG9jAclE/X41wSrsqqNI/AAAAAAAAMek/pGuRB9PaWMAH7j13gDBuM-CYHzemQ5lQgCLcBGAsYHQ/w640-h215/andre-sanano-gQ06DrUzNIk-unsplash.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Third slide label</h5>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

*Note:* My lack of skills in HTML is compensated by my expertise in TEX :), so the first thing I thought when I saw this problem was: 'Humm, If I only had something like \vspace{...}.' Do you know anything similar for HTML?

Comment: In order to properly address the issue as it pertains to your HTML or CSS we would need to see said HTML / CSS.  Can you provide the minimal code necessary for this particular part of your project?

Comment: Ok. I just uploaded it.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it. Adding CSS to my template (just before ]]></b:skin>):

```
#Label{
margin-top: 2px;
}
```

[image]

Replace **Label** with your widget name. Use margin-bottom if you want to reduce the space after the widget.